# How to add attribute for outermost decorator?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

hope someone can shed some light on this:

I have a decorator which wraps `tr`/`td` tags on various elements. So far, so good. However, I have a 'break' element, which puts in a blank area on a form to help grouping.

This has the following PHP:

```
public $elementBreakDecorator = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'form_break')),
    array('label', array('tag' => 'td', 'colspan'=> '4')),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
);
```

Used as follows:

```
$this->addElement('hidden', 'break', array(
    'decorators' => $this->elementBreakDecorator,
    'label' => 'Optional text for break element')            
);
```

And generated the following markup:

```
<tr>
    <td id="break-label">
        <label for="break" colspan="4" class="optional">Optional text for break element</label>
    </td>
    <td class="form_break">
        <input type="hidden" name="break" value="" id="break" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I need though, is the `colspan` to appear in the `break-label` tag, not the `label` tag. I have tried different arrangements but can't get it to place where I want.

Anybody got an idea of what I'm missing?

*Note:*
This is similar to 5332832, but `tagClass` only writes a `class=xx` into the tag. The other answers don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would remove the Label decorator and I would add a prepend custom decorator.

Here is the [website (wiip.fr)](http://wiip.fr/content/decorator-pour-ajouter-un-suffixe-ou-un-prefixe-a-un-zend_form_element) that allowed me to know this technique (in French but the examples are clear), otherwise, I found [it](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/).There are certainly others :) 

I hope it works for you. :)